# What happens if in a priority queue, 2 elements have same value and they are the heads, and queue.poll() is called?

Tags: java

My priority queue is removing 2 events but not calling the 2 functions corresponding to those 2 events.

I defined a function to check the queue size and also the queue contents and it is indeed removing the two events.

```
PriorityQueue<Event> queue;

public EventQueue()
{
    queue = new PriorityQueue<Event>(new EventComparator());
}

public void addEvent(Event event)
{
    queue.add(event);
}

public void processEvents()
{
    while(queue.isEmpty() == false && queue.peek().getEventTime() <= Clock.getCurrentTime())
    {
        Event event = queue.poll();
        event.getProcessingElement().handleEvent(event);
    }
}

public int getQueueSize()
{
    return queue.size();
}

public void displayQtimes()
{
    Object[] arr = queue.toArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) 
        System.out.print(arr[j]+" ");
        System.out.println();
}
```

When processEvent() is called, if two of the top elements have same EventTime, then handleEvent() of both the events should get called. But only one is happenning

Comment: I think you've worked it out yourself, a queue can only have one head; in the event of a tie only one can "win".

Comment: That's true, it should remove one head once and then the second head. It is doing that. But the second head's function is not getting called @ElliottFrisch

Comment: There's no issue in the way you use the priority queue. Can we see the code of `Event` class and especially what `getProcessingElement()` and `handleEvent(event)` methods do?